# Removing the white space in a CSS used on a mobile menu in a web site

Tags: css, mobile

I'm styling the mobile version of my website using CSS, and at the top the menu has a white space. I want this white space to be blank, or blue.

I have tried to change it, but it has changed the entire menu to transparent or blue.

Is there a way to change this, or is there a way to add a blue block which only appears at the top, behind the logo and behind the menu toggle, but in front of the white blank space?

The site is www.sassco.co.uk and you can see the issue when you collapse it to mobile.

Comment: Can you add enough code to reproduce the problem in the question itself? This is unlikely to help other people with a similar issue in the future when the content at the URL is changed/removed.

Comment: Hi. I just tend to use firebug to right click and check the css and experiment with no luck.

Comment: Hi, I tried checking your code in browser developer option, and found that media query @media handheld, only screen and (max-width: 767px) {} not written properly, hence its not working and showing white background to back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.navbar-inner {
    background-image:none;
    border:none;
}
```

Took me awhile to figure out what that bar was. Is this what you needed to change?

EDIT: After changing the top bar background color the new css effected the dropdown links background color. To fix this and to change the dropdown list background color use the css below. This will style the anchor tags:

```
#fav-navbar-collapse li a {
  background: rgb(230,230,230);
}
```

Comment: That's the correct CSS line, but when I change the background, it also changes the drop down menu on mobile.

Comment: I added css in my answer to change the background color of the dropdown links. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Absolutely spot on. Now on the collapsed mobile version, the menu bar and drop down looks very neat. Thanks!